# Why code is still running after "return"

Tags: java, recursion

I find that my code is still running after hitting the "return table;" (I've run the debug mode and it really moves forward to next line, how come? Shouldn't my function end(exit) immediately, once the return statement is called? Is there something wrong with my recursion?

```
public static HtmlTable getTableFromDomElement(DomElement element) throws Exception{

    if(element instanceof com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable){
        System.out.println("----YES!!!!-----");
        HtmlTable table = (HtmlTable) element;
        return table;
    }

    for(DomElement e : element.getChildElements()){         
            getTableFromDomElement(e);
        }

    throw new Exception("No HTML table found");
}
```

Output:

`----YES!!!!-----`

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: No HTML table found`

Comment: If an inner recursive call is printing the output then clearly an outer recursive call is going to reach the exception.  Since the very next line after the recursive call returns is to throw the exception.

Answer (score 5):

You need to stop searching when you find, but you're not stopping your `for` loop. Instead, return `null` for the "not found" case and return the first time you see non-null:

```
public static HtmlTable getTableFromDomElement(DomElement element) throws Exception {
    HtmlTable table;

    if(element instanceof HtmlTable){
        System.out.println("----YES!!!!-----");
        table = (HtmlTable) element;
        return table;
    }

    for(DomElement e : element.getChildElements()){         
         table = getTableFromDomElement(e);
         if (table != null) {
             return table;
         }
    }

    return null;
}
```

(Remove the `throws Exception` if nothing that code is calling throws exceptions anymore.) Also note that since you're clearly importing `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html` (otherwise, your `HtmlTable` return type declaration wouldn't work), there's no need for `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable` in your `instanceof` check. Just `HtmlTable` is all you need.

If you need a version that throws when it's not found, it will have to be a wrapper function.

```
public static HtmlTable getTableFromDomElementOrThrow(DomElement element) throws Exception{
    HtmlTable table = getTableFromDomElement(element);
    if (table == null) {
        throw new Exception("No HTML table found");
    }
    return table;
}
```

(Well, it doesn't **have** to be a wrapper function, you could catch the exception in each iteration of your loop, but since child elements not having the table is not an exceptional condition, it's not an appropriate place to throw an exception. It would also be markedly less efficient to throw exceptions on each loop iteration.)

---

Or here's a refactored version that only returns in one place (sometimes considered good practice):

```
public static HtmlTable getTableFromDomElement(DomElement element) throws Exception {
    HtmlTable table = null;

    if(element instanceof HtmlTable){
        System.out.println("----YES!!!!-----");
        table = (HtmlTable) element;
    } else {
        for (DomElement e : element.getChildElements()){         
             table = getTableFromDomElement(e);
             if (table != null) {
                 break;
             }
        }
    }

    return table;
}
```